# ¿Cómo acceder a un directorio oculto en linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Me gustaría saber cómo acceder a un directorio que se encuentra oculto en una carpeta en específico. Lo he intentado de esta manera y no me lo permite hacer:

```
cd .nombre_carpeta
```

Sí puedo visualizar el directorio pero, aun siendo usuario root, no me permite acceder a esa carpeta y la ruta por lo general es `/etc/init.d/pgagent`.

Comment: cd .nombre_carpeta

Comment: Ya lo he intentado de esa manera y no me lo permite hacer

Comment: Entonces en una próxima ocasión pon lo que has intentando.
En ese caso es posible que no se cuente con los permisos adecuados. Es bueno también colocar lo que se intenta y si sale algún error. La comunidad no es telepata!

Comment: prueba no como sudo sino como root para ver si asi te deja ver el directorio...

Comment: Puedes listar los dir ocultos con ls -la

Comment: si claro yo los listo y me muestra que solo el usuario root y grupo root tiene permisos sobre esa carpeta, pero al intentar acceder no me lo permite

Comment: si puedo visualizar el directorio pero aun siendo usuario root no me permise acceder a esa carpeta y la ruta por lo general es /etc/init.d/pgagent

Comment: Estás seguro de que es una carpeta? no será un archivo? Haz un `ls-la` para confirmar, y si es posible peganos la salida para ver los permisos

Comment: Hola @JhonDemberMurilloMendez, por favor edita la pregunta para añadir más información: el comando que estás ejecutando y falla, el error que recibes cuando ejecutas el comando, y más información sobre el directorio (permisos, tipo, etc.) Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Daré por hecho que conoces la ruta y el nombre del directorio.

Por lo que lo que necesitas es:

```
cd carpeta_en_especifico/.directorio_oculto
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba el nombre del directorio:

```
ls -a
```

Intenta acceder al directorio con la siguiente orden:

```
cd ./.directorio_oculto
```